# (Yii2) RangeValidator validation correctness

Tags: validation, model, yii2

In app/models/Model
this validates

```
//simulating incorrect user input
//$model->status='some-string';

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [0]], //asserts true (why?)
      //['status', 'in', 'range' => [0], 'strict' => true], //asserts false (correct)

    ];
}
```

EDIT: I have updated this question to reflect new insights.

Comment: Tested and it's working with constant.

Comment: seems like problem is not in this code

Comment: Humh, it seems that if $model->status is input as "some-string", the validator will assert that as equal to 0, unless strict mode is used. So the issue is not the constant, but the comparision itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you define your constant inside in model class

```
 class model extends activeRecord {
const STATUS = 0;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['status'], 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS]],
    ];
}
}
```

Try this it works for me.....

Answer (score 0):

status is most likely empty at the time of the validation, the internal checks compute to something like:

```
// non-strict:
null == 0  // this is true

// strict:
null === 0 // this is false
```

same applies with empty string, see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)